# Controlling Metaball Subdivision and Collision

Tags: particles, topology, collision

These are actually two questions. For the context:
I am trying to make an animated lava lamp and thought metaballs are very fitting for that use case. I created a particle emitter that uses a metaball as an object reference for the particles. I use the case shape of the lamp itself for the collision detection.

First problem:
I noticed that the emitted metaballs are very low-poly, which (even with a material applied) is very obvious as seen in the first screenshot (the lower blob of the two).

[image]

So my question here is very simple: **Is there a way to subdivide metaballs or any other way to make them look less low-poly on smaller scales?** I can't find anything in the metaballs tab and apparently modifiers can't be applied to metaballs either. I also noticed that when upscaled, metaballs would adjust their subdivision accordingly but even if I scale my entire scene, the metaballs emitted are still too small to have higher topo.

Second problem: I used the shape of the lamp as the object with collision physics enabled. The particles do bounce off of it, but this only gets triggered when the particles are a certain amount outside of the collision object.

[image]

I tried setting an inner thickness to the physics setting but that wouldn't help.
**Isn't there a setting that detects collision already when any vertex is outside / on the collision object?**

Comment: Please do not include two questions in one. Meanwhile, I have actually had difficulty getting Metaballs to emit as particles at all, though you can turn up their resolution fairly easily when they are not particles.